# DateDiff to find duration in minutes not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using `DATEDIFF(MI,STARTDATE,ENDDATE)`

I tried using `MINUTE` and `N`, but none of them are producing the expected result. Whenever the difference is 50 seconds, it is showing 1 minute.

I am using SQL Server 2008, and all the date times are in UTC format.

My Start Date is a database record and End Date is `GETUTCDATE()`.

Answer (score 4):

`DATEDIFF` returns the count (signed integer) of the specified datepart boundaries crossed between the specified startdate and enddate.  For example, this query will return `1` as a minute boundary has been crossed between the two times:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,'5 May 2015 11:59:00','5 May 2015 12:00:01')
```

You could use this statement instead:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(s,DATEADD(s,-50,GETUTCDATE()),GETUTCDATE()) / 60
```